# Ants on my lemon tree

Tags: trees, pest-control, lemons

I have noticed a big trail of ants on my lemon tree. I’ve tried spraying water; I’ve tried spraying vinegar; I’ve placed any traps but nothing seems to work. What can I do, without spraying toxic chemicals on my lemon tree?

Comment: Are you sure the ants are a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Ants are going to the lemon tree to harvest the sap from aphids.  Get rid of the aphids and the ants will go elsewhere.

Soap and water mixed at a rate of 5 ml soap to 1 liter of water and sprayed on the top and bottom of the leaves and stems at five day intervals at least three times should get rid of the aphids which are soft bodied and have no resistance to soap.

You should:

- confirm that aphids are present by adding a picture
- look for other plants that may have pests as well

Comment: Also scale insects attract ants. In my experience they may be more frequent on lemons.